Outlook 2019 start stuck at "Processing..." only with a specific Office 365 user
Last week the problem showed up at a user that Outlook 2019 did not want to start anymore.
It loads a few things and then it stuck at the start screen with "Processing...".
I have tried to disable all the plugins in safe mode, created a new user profile, repaired the Office 2019 installation, but nothing helped.


Since it was a pretty old laptop with W10 I decided to order a new laptop and installed Office 2019 on it.
After the user logged in there, the same problem occurred. It only happens with that specific user (U1) but not with another user (U2).
If I log in with U2 at W11 and setup U1 in Outlook 2019 then it does not start.
The other way around, U1 logged in at W11, U2 configured in Outlook 2019 works.
This means to me there must be a problem with the Office 365 / Exchange Online user account.
I did not change anything on that specific user (U1) and it worked well for about 1.5 years.
There is a link to a Reddit post, but no solution showed up there so far:
What could cause such an issue and where could I start to debug such a problem?

Given that the problem persists across different devices and operating systems for the same user (U1), it does indeed seem likely that the issue is related to the Office 365 / Exchange Online user account.
Here are a few additional steps you can try to resolve this issue:

Sometimes, corrupted cache files can cause issues. You can clear the cache by deleting the OST file for the user. Outlook will recreate it the next time it starts.
If the user's mailbox is very large, it might cause performance issues. You can check the mailbox size and archive old emails if necessary.
Use the Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant (SaRA) tool to diagnose and fix issues with the user's mailbox. This tool can help identify and resolve problems with Outlook and Office 365.
Although you've already created a new profile, try deleting the existing profile completely and then creating a new one from scratch.
Ensure that there are no other software or security settings that might be interfering with Outlook. Sometimes, antivirus or firewall settings can cause issues.



I have multriple times tried that and now I am even on a brand new laptop.
It has just 19 GB used of 50 GB in total.
SaRA does not start anymore in W11, it just opens a useless help window. (https://i.imgur.com/LXMzkPW.png, https://i.imgur.com/o8d0DVz.png)
I have tried that multiple times as well.
No security software is installed yet.


I just found the solution:

Run "Outlook.exe /nopreview"

Open the Inbox

Change the view to single


Open Outlook on the regular way and change the view back.


Unbelievable, I spent 10+ hours with that issue.

Not for nothing, but you can always open a support case from your O365 tenant. There's no cost to do so. Even though your issue was with Outlook 2019, they would have assisted since this issue was for a licensed O365 user.

Considering the steps you've already taken, you can try some more advanced solutions:
Some modern Microsoft applications, including Outlook, rely on WebView. If it's missing or corrupted, it can cause problems. Try reinstalling it from Microsoft's official website to see if that helps.
Since the problem seems to be specific to U1, there may be corrupted settings in the user's Office 365 account. You can try the following:

Sometimes, resetting the password can refresh the account settings.
Temporarily remove the Office 365 license from U1, wait a few minutes, and then reassign it. This can sometimes resolve account-related issues.
Check the user account settings in the Office 365 admin center for any anomalies. Look for any unusual configurations or policies that may affect Outlook.
You've tried disabling add-ins, but running Outlook in safe mode can sometimes bypass other issues. To do this, press Win + R, type outlook.exe /safe, and then press Enter.
Since the problem persists on different devices, try creating a brand new Windows profile for U1 and then setting up Outlook. This can help isolate if the problem is with the user's Windows profile.
Sometimes a large or corrupted email message can cause problems. Use Outlook Web Access (OWA) to check and delete any suspicious email messages.


More useful information, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/answers/questions/776586/outlook-2019-hangs-on-processing-why-and-how-to-fi
